# Como manipular una columna con un nombre usado por las querys en SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla en SQL server con el nombre *default*, pero el problema es que SQL usa la palabra 'default' para hacer otra cosa. Entonces no puedo manipular la columna *default* de mi tabla. ¿de qué manera puedo hacerlo? No puedo editar el nombre de la variable pues la tabla no es mía.

Comment: puedes al usarla colocarle un alias a la columna

Comment: No entiendo a qué te refieres con ponerle alias a la columna. Lo que digo es que por ejemplo no puedo hacer:

`select default as foo
from TABLE`

porque default sql lo usa para otra cosa

Comment: Hola Eduardo me parece que debes especificarle al motor hay varias opciones para probar una es usando comillas `` y otra puede ser "select table.default from table"

Comment: Si bien se puede realizar con comillas de identificación o con table.default. Yo te sugiero solicites el cambio del nombre, ya que es una palabra reservada [Palabras reservadas SQL Server Compact](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms173340(v=sql.110).aspx) y por regla no se deben usar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el caso de SQL Server puedes usar uno de los [delimitadores de identidad](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-2017) para diferenciar el nombre de esa columna de las palabras reservadas:

- `[]`
- `""`

Dado que `default` es una [palabra reservada](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), entonces puedes escribir la consulta así:

```
select [default] as foo from TABLE
```

O bien así:

```
select "default" as foo from TABLE
```

Aunque no es recomendable usar palabras reservadas para nombres de tablas o columnas.

Comment: Estimado, Gracias! Esto me sirvió! La tabla no la genero yo, así que por eso tiene esos nombres.

Comment: @EduardoHuerta Me alegro. Si no hay otra opción, lo único que no tienes que olvidar es poner los delimitadores cada vez que vayas a usar la columna. Saludos.